# How to add widget area in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want toadd a widget area in my main section where recent posts were display. But i can't be able to do. Here what i wanted to do.
[image]

So the red rectangle widget area i want to add. But every time i insert a code of adding widget to my function.php file it's add an widget area in sidebar.
Please friends anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: Please show your code, so we can help you...

Comment: Also, are you using one of those popular themes from a marketplace or wordpress.org repository? You can usually find wicked good documentation for most of them...

Answer (score 3):

**1. Define a new widget area with [register_sidebar()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)**

**2. Generate widget ouput with [dynamic_sidebar()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)**

> **Note:** This must not be inside of a sidebar, you can place the widget output where you want.

Read [Widgetizing Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) for more informations and examples.

---

### Example:

**Create a new widgetarea**: (place it in your `functions.php`)

```
function my_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'id'            => 'above-recent-posts',
        'name'          => 'Widgets above recent posts',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

**Output widgets**: (place this where you want the widgets should appear)

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'above-recent-posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's simple.

**1. Add the widget display code to the theme files.**

> locate the part where you want to show the widget and add the following code

```
if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
   dynamic_sidebar( 'id-of-the-widget-area' );
}
```

This will display your widget area in the area where you added the code.

**2. You can also display the widget through plugin**

> if there is a hook in the theme file, and you know that specific hook. Then adding the following code to your plugin file will display the specific widget

```
add_action('replace_with_specific_hook_in_theme', 'my_custom_widget_area');
function my_custom_widget_area() {

    // Optional: Check if you are on the specific page

    if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')) {
       dynamic_sidebar( 'id-of-the-widget-area' );
    }

}
```